# Monitoring Clementine with DBus using Python

Tags: python, media-player, monitoring, dbus

I'd like to do the exact same thing that is explained here :

[How to continuously monitor rhythmbox for track change using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919735/how-to-continuously-monitor-rhythmbox-for-track-change-using-python)

but with Clementine instead of Rhythmbox.

Problem is, I couldn't find the equivalent of *playingUriChanged* to give to the *connect_to_signal* method.

The only thing I could find with qdbus that seemed relevant was

```
signal void org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer.TrackChange(QVariantMap)
```

but it takes a parameter.

I'm not familiar with DBus so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not take a parameter, it returns parameter (hash map)

code extracted from [this script](http://svn.tribler.org/vlc/trunk/extras/misc/mpris.py):

```
def TrackChange(Track):
    # use Track["URI"], Track["title"], Track["artist"] etc

def Connect(name):
    global root, player, tracklist

    # first we connect to the objects
    root_o = bus.get_object(name, "/")
    player_o = bus.get_object(name, "/Player")
    tracklist_o = bus.get_object(name, "/TrackList")

    # there is only 1 interface per object
    root = dbus.Interface(root_o, "org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer")
    tracklist  = dbus.Interface(tracklist_o, "org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer")
    player = dbus.Interface(player_o, "org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer")

    # connect to the TrackChange signal
    player_o.connect_to_signal("TrackChange", TrackChange, dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer")
```